# How to make AnimatedSwitcher animate if parent widget is rebuilt in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to implement a selectable `ListTile`. When `ListTile` is selected it's leading icon changes and its background color changes. I am trying to use **AnimatedSwitcher** to animate the transition when icons are changed. And it works (as long as I don't change background color of the list tile).

Changing the background color of the `ListTile` causes the animation to not work anymore. And I think I know why that is. When background color of the `ListTile` is changed, entire `ListTile` gets rebuilt. Which causes `AnimatedSwitcher` to also be rebuilt instead of transitioning between icons. Is there a way I can implement what I am trying to do. Here is my full code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool change = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: SomeStatelessWidget(
                AnimatedSwitcher(
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                  child: change
                      ? CircleAvatar(
                          key: UniqueKey(),
                          child: Icon(Icons.check),
                        )
                      : CircleAvatar(
                          key: UniqueKey(),
                          child: Text("A"),
                        ),
                  transitionBuilder: (child, animation) {
                    return RotationTransition(
                      turns: animation,
                      child: child,
                    );
                  },
                ),
                change),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.swap_horiz),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                change = !change;
              });
            },
          ),
          floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        ));
  }
}

class SomeStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final bool changed;

  SomeStatelessWidget(this.child, this.changed);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: changed
          ? BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).selectedRowColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle)
          : null,
      child: ListTile(
        leading: child,
        title: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text("This is an example"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `decoration: 
          BoxDecoration(
              color: changed? Theme.of(context).selectedRowColor : Colors.transparent,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle)
          ,`

Comment: @pskink add to Answer. I'll mark it answered.